# Apply-Scale withouth breaking particles

Tags: particles, hair

Is there a way to "apply-scale" to a character who has already been groomed without messing up the particles size? * I’ve already tried "disconnect and connect hair ", it didn’t work. Thanks

Comment: Hair systems use velocity values and those values are relative to object size, so I think it will be... er... hairy...  You could try multiplying velocity values by your final scale and then apply scale, but I'm not sure how it will work out.

Comment: Actually after a groom I'm thinking those values aren't even able to be changed...